# React Native Animated Multiple Animations on one element

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, animation, react-animated

Is there a way to have multiple animations on a single Animated View, changing the same css property?

```
this.expandAnimation = new Animated.Value(50);
this.shrinkAnimation = new Animated.Value(200);

Animated.sequence([
  Animated.timing(this.expandAnimation, {
    toValue: 200,
    duration: 1000
  }),
  Animated.timing(this.shrinkAnimation, {
    toValue: 50,
    duration: 1000
  })
]),

  <Animated.View style={[styles.box, { width: this.ExpandAnimation }]}> // What value to bind to width?
    <View>
    </View>
  </Animated.View>
```

Comment: Just have a single animated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Federkun. You use a single animated value.

```
this.expandAndShrinkAnimation = new Animated.Value(50);

Animated.sequence([
  Animated.timing(this.expandAndShrinkAnimation, {
    toValue: 200,
    duration: 1000
  }),
  Animated.timing(this.expandAndShrinkAnimation, {
    toValue: 50,
    duration: 1000
  })
]),

  <Animated.View style={[styles.box, { width: this.expandAndShrinkAnimation }]}> // What value to bind to width?
    <View>
    </View>
  </Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the Animation on Parallel see this [Demo link](https://snack.expo.dev/@mirza009/animated-translate)